# How to refresh the histogram for webcamera in real-time in EmguCV C#?

Tags: c#, emgucv

[image]Can anyone please help me out in continuously refreshing the histogram in histogram box in real-time from webcamera using EmguCv C#..

```
HistogramBox hb = new HistogramBox();
Form frm = new Form();

hb.GenerateHistograms(img, 256);// show 256 shades
hb.Enabled = true;

hb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(255, 255);// change to your preferred size 
frm.Controls.Add(hb);
hb.Refresh();   

frm.ShowDialog();
```

This is snippet i got but when i include in webcamera capture method the dialogbox refreshes such that it goes blank rather than updating.

---

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
namespace Redcolor_tracker_GUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Capture capWebcam = null;
        bool inProcess = false;
        Image<Bgr, Byte> img;
        Image<Gray, Byte> imgout;
        HistogramBox hb = new HistogramBox();
        bool toggle = false;
        Form frm = new Form();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                capWebcam = new Capture();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException except)
            {
                txtXYRadius.Text = except.Message;
                return;
            }
            Application.Idle += processFrameGUI;
            inProcess = true;


        }
        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (capWebcam != null)
            {
                capWebcam.Dispose();
            }
        }
        void processFrameGUI(object sender,EventArgs srg)
        {
            img=capWebcam.QueryFrame();
            if(img==null) return;
            imgout=img.InRange(new Bgr(0,0,0),new Bgr(0,0,0));
            imgout=imgout.SmoothGaussian(9);
            if (toggle)
            {

              hb.GenerateHistograms(img, 256);
              hb.Refresh();// show 256 shades
              hb.Enabled = true;

             }
            ibOriginal.Image=img;
            ibProcessed.Image=imgout;
         }

        private void btnPauseOResume_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (inProcess == true)
            {
                Application.Idle -= processFrameGUI;
                inProcess = false;
                btnPauseOrResume.Text = "resume";
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Idle += processFrameGUI;
                inProcess = true;
                btnPauseOrResume.Text = "resume";
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (toggle == false)
            {
                toggle = true;
            }
            else
            {
                toggle = false;
            }

            hb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 400);

            frm.Controls.Add(hb);
            frm.ShowDialog();  
        }

    }
}
```

ENTIRE CODE******************

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us your refresh loop, i.e. the loop that gets the camera image and creates the histogramm?

Comment: I have added the image of how it refreshes the histogram.It just stacks one below the other.It happens so quick that i cant take screenshot.@Abbondanza

Comment: I meant that you need to provide the code snippet where you get the image from the camera and update the histogram with it. There must be a loop doing that. Show us this loop please. I suspect that you are calling `frm.Controls.Add(hb)` within this loop which means you are adding the same (or maybe even a new)  `HistogramBox` to your `Controls` each render cycle.

Comment: I have added the entire code.Also please can u help me out with how to extract the values from histogram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `ClearHistogram()` inside `processFrameGUI(object sender,EventArgs srg)`:

```
void processFrameGUI(object sender,EventArgs srg)
{
    img=capWebcam.QueryFrame();
    if(img==null) return;
    imgout=img.InRange(new Bgr(0,0,0),new Bgr(0,0,0));
    imgout=imgout.SmoothGaussian(9);
    if (toggle)
    {
      // Note the following line:
      hb.ClearHistogram();
      hb.GenerateHistograms(img, 256);
      hb.Refresh();// show 256 shades
      hb.Enabled = true;

     }
    ibOriginal.Image=img;
    ibProcessed.Image=imgout;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update the `HistogramBox` control in a separate worker-thread by calling its `Refresh` method in a defined intervals (with a timer, for example). Just note that you should marshal the refresh calls into the UI thread by referring to its SyncContext.

**Example:**

```
//Runs on a worker Thread
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    hb.Refresh();; // Runs on UI thread
});
```